# Help with prove of inf.

Tags: calculus, supremum-and-infimum

I need to prove that:

$$\inf\{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3n+1}{6n^2} \Big| n\in\mathbb N\}=\frac{1}{3}$$

I get stuck with my proof, I'll write it down.

$$n\geq1$$
$$3n\geq3$$
$$3n+1\geq4$$
$$\frac{1}{3}+3n+1\geq4+\frac{1}{3}$$

Now, I'm having a problem with $6n^2$ if I multiply by $6n^2$, I'll get variable in the express of $4+\frac{1}{3}$.

Any ideas?, Thanks!

Comment: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left[\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3n+1}{6n^2} \right]=\frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Remind that $m=\inf A\iff \forall\varepsilon>0$ there exists $a\in A$ such that $a<m-\varepsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let:
$$
S = 
\left\{\frac{1}{3} + \frac{3n + 1}{6n^2} ~\middle|~ n \in \mathbb N\right\}
$$
Notice that since $3n + 1 > 0$ and $6n^2 > 0$, we know that $\frac{3n + 1}{6n^2} > 0$ so that $\frac{1}{3}$ is a lower bound for $S$. It remains to show that $\frac{1}{3}$ is the **greatest** lower bound.

To this end, choose any $\epsilon > 0$. Now recall that, by the Archimedean property, there is some $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $N > \frac{2}{3\epsilon}$. But then since $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{3N + 1}{6N^2} \in S$ and:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{3} + \frac{3N + 1}{6N^2}
&< \frac{1}{3} + \frac{3N + N}{6N^2} &\text{since }N > 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3N} \\
&< \frac{1}{3} + \epsilon &\text{since }N > \frac{2}{3\epsilon} \iff \epsilon > \frac{2}{3N} \\
\end{align*}
it follows that $\frac{1}{3} = \inf S$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

First note that ${1 \over 3} + { 3n+1 \over 6n^2} \ge {1 \over 3}$, so ${1 \over 3} $ is a lower bound.

Now let $\epsilon >0$ and choose $n$ large enough so that ${ 3n+1 \over 6n^2} < \epsilon$. (One easy way is to choose $n$ large enough so that ${1 \over n } < \epsilon$, then $\epsilon > { 1\over n} = { 6 n \over 6 n^2} > { 4n \over 6 n^2} \ge  {3n+1 \over 6 n^2}$.)

Then ${1 \over 3} + { 3n+1 \over 6n^2} < {1 \over 3}+ \epsilon$.

It follows that ${ 1\over 3} = \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} ({1 \over 3} + { 3n+1 \over 6n^2} )$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

Obviously $\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3n+1}{n^2}\geq\frac{1}{3}.$ The sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3n+1}{n^2}$ converges to $\frac{1}{3}$ since $\frac{3n+1}{n^2}$ behaves like $\frac{1}{n}.$ Thus $a_n\rightarrow \frac{1}{3}.$ whcih is to say $\inf=\frac{1}{3}$